# creating a string with a mac address inside

Tags: java, string

I want to send a string message containing 2 int values and a mac address. I mean something like this:

```
String loadMessage = String.format("LoadOn %1$d %2$d %3$?", nodeid, sum, macAddress)
```

macAddress variable is MacAddress type: org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.MacAddress

What should I put in `%3$?`? I know that for integer values we use %d, how about a mac address?

And when my receiver gets this message, how can it split the message in order to find out the mac address? I mean for example for finding out the nodeid value which is an integer, we can do something like this:

```
String[] partss = message.split(" ");
int id = Integer.parseInt(partss[1]);
```

Receiver has got this string and wants to extract the macAddress value from this string (like what he/she has done for integer extraction). How can he do this?

Comment: MAC address is just a number, I assume you want to send it as human-readable form (e.g. AA:BB:CC:DD:EE)?

Comment: @m0skit0 I want the receiver to be able to convert it to a MAC address. As what it does for figuring out the integer value from the received string: *int id = Integer.parseInt(partss[1]);*

Comment: I'll try a different wording: a MAC address is a 48-bit number, in which format you want to send/receive it?

Comment: @m0skit0 I'm using a byte array for sending and receiving, but my question is about formatting the string which is supposed to be converted to the byte array. I can't understand how I can place a macaddress variable inside a string, as I can place an int or another string inside it.

Comment: What is the variable type of `macAddress`?

Comment: It's MacAddress: org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.MacAddress

Comment: @helen You never answered the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508948/creating-a-string-with-a-mac-address-inside#comment95821378_54508948): Which format you want the string to be? --- Doesn't the `toString` implementation of `MacAddress` already format it correctly for you? Presumably, the `toString` representation would be what [`MacAddress.of(String macString)`](http://floodlight.github.io/floodlight/javadoc/openflowj-loxi/org/projectfloodlight/openflow/types/MacAddress.html#of-java.lang.String-) would be able to parse back into a `MacAddress` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MacAddress type will need some sort of .toString() method in order to be properly placed in the desired string. Otherwise you will have to pass it to the receiver through a separate method from including it in the string.

If you can pass in your MAC address as a string and split it on the receiving end and parse it from there. If you were to follow your trend with getting "nodeid" and store it in a string or int array:

String Array:

```
// Assuming partss[3] = "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA" 
String[] mac = partss[3].split(":");
```

Directly to int Array:

```
int[] mac = Arrays.stream(loadMessage[3].split(":"))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

You can otherwise take it directly as a string and recreate another MacAddress type out of it on the receiving end. I was unable to find any documentation on it.